# One function for handling char* and wchar_t*

Tags: c++, templates, char, wchar-t, wchar

Right now I have two functions which do the exact same parsing stuff, one for `char*` and one for `wchar_t*`. I'd like to have just one function so that I only need to change it once (for consistency). Converting the whole string to `char*` or `wchar_t*` is not an option as the string can be very long and should not be duplicated in memory.

Only difference in the two functions is that I have to use `'a'` for `char*` vs. `L'a'` for `wchar_t*`.

Is there a way (e.g., using template meta programming) to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt this could be solved with a template reasonably if you need the literals inside of your parser. Might be a valid use case for preprocessor macros.

Comment: he could use `char/char*` literals and then "cast" it to the appropriate type

Comment: Are you willing to rely on `wchar_t('a') == L'a'` ? This is formally not portable, but it can be verified with a `static_assert`. I.e. it works on sane systems and doesn't compile elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only one or a limited number of literals a simple overload could do the job.

```
wchar_t a(const wchar_t* text) { return L'a'; }
char a(const char* text) { return 'a'; }

template<typename T>
void parse(const T* text)
{
    auto t = a(text);
    find(text, t);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sounds tedious for writing a whole parser.

Comment: It solves the problem I understood from "Only difference in the two functions is that I have to use 'a' for char* vs. L'a' for wchar*.", not the problems you expect the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with traits and without macros, but it's cumbersome and error-prone, because every char or string literal has to be repeated in both template specialisations. C++11's `auto` helps a little, though:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <class CharType>
struct MyTraits
{
};

template <>
struct MyTraits<char>
{
    static auto constexpr a = 'a';
    static auto constexpr foo = "foo";
    static auto constexpr lb = '\n';
};

template <>
struct MyTraits<wchar_t>
{
    static auto constexpr a = L'a';
    static auto constexpr foo = L"foo";
    static auto constexpr lb = L'\n';
};

template <class CharType>
void f(std::basic_ostream<CharType>& os, std::basic_string<CharType> const& s)
{
    os << s << MyTraits<CharType>::a << MyTraits<CharType>::foo << MyTraits<CharType>::lb;
}

int main()
{
    f(std::cout, std::string("bar"));
    f(std::wcout, std::wstring(L"bar"));
}
```

A long-term solution is to get rid of the necessity (or feature?) to support both character types.